# Safari ios 13 : DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission() on cross origin iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, permissions, ios13

With the new permission request API introduced in Safari on iOS 13, I get this error when doing the permission request on a cross origin iframe:
*Call to requestPermission() failed, reason: Source frame did not have the same security origin as the main page.*

I could not find any corresponding Feature-Policy to add to the iframe "allow" property: neither 'accelerometer' or 'gyroscope' worked...

Is there a way to allow DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission() on cross domain iframe?

Comment: Lune, did you ever find a solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that worked for me is redirecting through the iframed domain once.

So, if you have abc.com and xyz.com is an iframe under abc.com, while landing to the abc.com, there needs to be an intermediate redirect through xyz.com only for the purpose of setting a blank cookie. Then Safari will allow setting a cookie from iframe for xyz.com.

I'm not sure if there's any other better workaround. However, this worked and served my purpose.

Thanks.